# Is there a way to way to use a VideoPlayer widget in place of an Image widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The `panorama` package on pub.dev only works with `Image` objects, but the premise should be the same if a video is used instead.

I want to modify this package to accept a `VideoPlayer` or `VideoPlayerController` widget from the `video_player` package. What are the things I must do to make it compatible?

The way `panorama` works is it takes the Image object and passes it to the package `flutter_cube` where it then makes a Mesh and texture out of it. The panorama viewing is done based off of this.

What I want to achieve is instead of Panorama accepting an Image widget, it should be the VideoPlayer widget. **Width** and **height** are really the only two variables needed so I wonder what I should do, those two are easily obtainable from the VideoPlayerController.

Comment: Did you try other packages like https://pub.dev/packages/video_360 this one? It would make more sense for me to try it out before modifying a package that was only built for pictures.

Comment: @targiasId Oh definitely, just that it's really outdated now and crashes on some types of videos. I tried updating that package and fixing it, but I can't get past OpenGL errors/crashes. EDIT: Actually on a second glance this is not the package I tried, it was `video_player_extra`, I'll try this one.